# Create Input Field on click at specific position

Tags: javascript, button

I got a form where I want to dynamically add input fields, if the users clicks on a "add more" button. At the moment it works to create the buttons on click, but the buttons do no get created at the position where I want them to be. Here is my HTML Code Snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var addMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#add-more1, #add-more2");
  addMoreButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(button);
      // Create a div
      var div = document.createElement("div");

      // Create a text input
      var text = document.createElement("input");
      text.setAttribute("type", "text");
      text.setAttribute("name", "More");
      text.setAttribute("placeholder", "Weitere hinzufügen");

      // add the file and text to the div
      div.appendChild(text);

      //Append the div to the container div
      document.querySelector(".buttonTest").appendChild(div);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="user-details">
  <div class="input-box">
    <span class="details">Stärken</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Stärken, z.B. 'Kommunikativ'" id="strenghts">
    <div class="buttonTest">
      <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more1">+ Weitere 
                    hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <span class="details">Technische Fähigkeiten</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Technische Fähigkeiten, z.B. 'JavaScript'" id="tech">
    <div class="buttonTest">
      <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more2">+ Weitere hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now every time when the first (#add-more1) or second (#add-more2) button is clicked, the input field gets created below the first button. But I want the input fields to appear where the button was clicked. For example:
If the first button is clicked I want the input field to be created below the first button. And if the second button is clicked I want the input field to be created below the second button and not below the first button.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parentElement

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

Example:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var addMoreButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#add-more1, #add-more2");
  addMoreButtons.forEach(function(button){
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(button);
      // Create a div
      var div = document.createElement("div");
  
      // Create a text input
      var text = document.createElement("input");
      text.setAttribute("type", "text");
      text.setAttribute("name", "More"); 
      text.setAttribute("placeholder", "Weitere hinzufügen");
  
      // add the file and text to the div
      div.appendChild(text);
  
      //Append the div to the container div
      button.parentElement.appendChild(div);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="user-details">
            <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Stärken</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Stärken, z.B. 'Kommunikativ'" id="strenghts">
                <div class="buttonTest">
                    <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more1">+ Weitere 
                    hinzufügen</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Technische Fähigkeiten</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Technische Fähigkeiten, z.B. 'JavaScript'" id="tech">
                <div class="buttonTest">
                    <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more2">+ Weitere hinzufügen</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code somewhat, using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and [`[element].insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add a text input element. For the new text input element, a copy of the old one is used. Using `insertAdjacentHTML` gives you control over the placement of the new element (here: *after* the div containing the clicked button, cf `afterend`).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const bttn = evt.target.closest(`.buttonTest`);
  if (bttn) {
    const inputElemCopy = bttn.closest(`.input-box`)
      .querySelector(`input`).cloneNode(true);
    inputElemCopy.name = `${inputElemCopy.id}_more`;
    inputElemCopy.removeAttribute(`id`);
    bttn.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `afterend`,
      `<div>${inputElemCopy.outerHTML}</div>`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="user-details">
  <div class="input-box">
    <span class="details">Stärken</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Stärken, z.B. 'Kommunikativ'" 
      id="strenghts">
    <div class="buttonTest">
      <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more1">+ Weitere 
        hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box">
    <span class="details">Technische Fähigkeiten</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Technische Fähigkeiten, z.B. 'JavaScript'" 
      id="tech">
    <div class="buttonTest">
      <button type="button" class="add-more" id="add-more2">+ Weitere 
        hinzufügen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```